# Calculating the first homology group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose all vertices on a polygon are identified and the polygon is $abcb^{-1}a^{-1}c$.  Is it enough to simply switch to additive notation, get $2c$ and realize that $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}^2$?  Does that mean it should be possible to cut-and-paste to get $aabbcc$? Is this always the case?

Comment: Yes, this is a correct procedure to determine the first homology group (you should be using the notation $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z^2$ - the asterisk is used to denote the free product, which is not abelian.) "Does this mean it should be possible to cut-and-paste to get $aabbcc$?" What's your reasoning here? Just because the two have the same homology doesn't mean they're homeomorphic. In this case, the two things you describe are indeed homeomorphic, but I don't see why you conclude this is the case.